# How to position axis label in highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts, axis

I have [image] the attached chart output.

How can I put the name of the axis exactly on the axis instead of positioning it between the axis (ie: N, E, S, W).

The JS code is given below:

```
window.chart = new Highcharts.Chart({

                    chart: {
                        renderTo: 'container2',
                        polar: true,
                        type: 'column'
                    },

                    title: {
                        text: '24-Hours Wind Speed and Direction Chart'
                    },

                    pane: {
                        startAngle: 0,
                        endAngle: 360,
                        size: '85%'
                    },
                    legend: {
                        reversed: true,
                        enabled: false,
                        align: 'right',
                        verticalAlign: 'top',
                        y: 100,
                        layout: 'vertical'
                    },
                    xAxis: {
                        type: "",
                        categories: sorted_names,           
                        labels: {
                            formatter: function () {
                                return this.value + '°';
                            }
                        }
                    },

                    yAxis: {
                        min: 0,
                        endOnTick: true,
                        showLastLabel: false
                    },

                    plotOptions: {
                        series: {
                        //   pointStart: 0,
                        //     pointInterval: 90
                       //   pointPlacement: 'between'
                        },
                        column: {
                            pointPadding: 0,
                            groupPadding: 0
                        }
                    },

                    series: series

                });
```

Is there anyone who can help me to fix this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can move it a little setting `xAxis` property `labels` to `align: 'right'`.

Comment: Is there any other way. It is not working actually in my case. Do you have any suggestions for me?

Comment: In my case `align: 'right'` move it a little counter-clockwise. I don't know if there is solution for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you are looking for a combination of the [tickMarkPlacement option](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.tickmarkPlacement) and the [pointPlacement](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.column.pointPlacement) option.

```
xAxis: {
    tickmarkPlacement: 'on', // add this!
    type: "",
    categories: sorted_names,           
    labels: {
        formatter: function () {
            return this.value + '°';
        }
    }
},
```

And in the plot options:

```
plotOptions: {
   series: {
       pointPlacement: 'on' // add this !
   },
   column: {
       pointPadding: 0,
       groupPadding: 0
   }
},
```

Here's a [fiddle demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/cUz7A/2/).

[image]

Comment: Awesome. It was beauty. :-) Thanks